# Using time delays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gif image that I want to stretch by making the height and/or width variable. However, I want the image stretching to be done at a speed I set, so it is progressive and visible as it occurs on the screen. The code below works, but it renders the image immediately as a complete image, with no stretching visible. So I thought: insert some kind of timer function to slow down the execution of the "stretching" code. I have tried setTimeout and setInterval (using 1/100 sec delays), but I have not been able to make either work. What am I doing wrong here guys?

```
$(window).load(function(){

  setInterval(function(){
            var i=1;
            for (i;i<400;i++) {
            $("#shape1").html('<img src="image.gif" width="'+i+'" height="40">');
            }
            },10);
      });
```

Comment: If you already use jQuery, why not use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and the easing functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems with your code are that

- at each interval iteration, you repeat the whole `for` loop
- you never stop the interval looping

You may fix your existing code like this :

```
var i=1;
function step() {
     $("#shape1").html('<img src="image.gif" width="'+i+'" height="40">');
     if (i++<400) setTimeout(step, 10);
}
step();
```

Instead of replacing the #shape1 content each time, you could also simply change the width :

```
var i=1;
var $img = $('<img src="image.gif" width=1 height="40">').appendTo('#shape1');
function step() {
     $img.css('width', i);
     if (i++<400) setTimeout(step, 10);
}
step();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ibEFEy/1/)

But jQuery has a very convenient [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function just for this kind of things.

Comment: you forgot to increment i.. i think

Comment: Probably best to manipulate the element, rather than replacing it.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand yes, that's why I recommend to use animate. But I felt it was important to explain what was wrong and how to fix it. You can't always rely on a library.

Comment: @dystroy, thanks, it works. I will also look into jQuery options you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As Dystroy suggested. Use jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead

```
setInterval(function(){
      var i=1;
      for (i;i<400;i++) {
          $("#shape1").animate({
              width : i
          },10);
      }
}, 10);
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/gE568/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transitions are great if your browser supports it.

```
.resize {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: width 1s ease;
}
```

Just add the class to an element to make it stretch out.

```
img.className = "resize";
```

### [css demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cQvSL/)

Comment: On checking, this appears to only work in Chrome, not FF or IE. Is there a way to make it work cross browser?

Comment: You can use CSS prefixes to improve support.

Comment: Is this what you mean? I am using:

 -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: width 1s ease-in-out;